# Clone/Copy, Edit then Add Dataset Row

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, datarow

### Background

I have a sql database bound Dataset that is the datasource of a Datagridview (dgv). I want to allow the user to copy and paste a row by right clicking on the rowheader and selecting an option from a context menu strip. Which i have done.

### Question

How do I copy, edit and then add a row?

The code i have so far, copies, edits both old and new rows then adds?

### Code Snippet

```
  //Get row
            var newrow = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"].Rows[rowIndex];

 //Duplicate row
            var copy = newrow;

    //Get next id of Identity Column of database
            var lastid =  getLastID() +1 ;

  //Sets the ID column of row to the nextID 
            copy[0] = lastid;

  JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"].ImportRow(copy);
```

Comment: `var copy = newrow;` will not duplicate the row but just copies the reference to an other variable. So change properties of one, will change properties of the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to copy a whole row from a previous one this is a possible way

```
// Row to copy from
DataRow dr = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"].Rows[rowIndex];

// Row that receives the values from source
DataRow newrow = JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"].NewRow();

// Copy the ItemArray of the source row to the destination row
// Note that this is not a reference copy.
// Internally a new object array is created when you _get_ the ItemArray
newrow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;

// Change whateever you need to change
newrow[0] = 99;

// Add the new row into the datatable collection
JoblistDataSet.Tables["Joblist"].Rows.Add(newrow);
```

Comment: Could you explain why we use an Item Array? Looks good though, thank you.

Comment: Simply because the _ItemArray_ is the property that keeps all the row values (IE the values of the columns for that row) When you write _var copy = newrow_ you are not creating a new row but force the _copy_ variable point at the same data of the _newrow_ variable. Instead you ask the datatable to create an empty row (with the same schema) for you and then place the ItemArray of the previous row in the new row. Internally the DataRow code makes a copy for you.